# Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1

Tags: cassandra

I'm having this issue below, I'm using google cloud VM

```
:~$ cqlsh

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

~$ cd /etc/cassandra/
```

I set my hosts like this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost



10.14*.0.* vm-1

10.15*.0.* vm-2
```

I got the ip from
ifconfig

```
vm-1 inet addr:10.14*.0.* Bcast:10.14*.0.* Mask:255.255.255.255

vm-2 inet addr:10.15*.0.* Bcast:10.15*.0.* Mask:255.255.255.255
```

in cassandra.yaml

I set in VM-2

```
listen_address: 10.15*.0.*

rpc_address: 10.15*.0.*
```

and in cassandra-env.sh

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.15*.0.*"

vm2@vm-2:/etc/cassandra$ netstat -nl | grep 7199
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

It works only if I do:

```
vm2@vm-2:/etc/cassandra$ cqlsh vm-2
Connected to dc1 at vm-2:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.6 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

Is it possible to change the default ip to the one I use in my Listen_address?

Answer (score -3):

Try using "cqlsh IP address". It should work.
You may also you username and password if you configured in the cassandra.yaml.